# curl_setopt() error while trying to get http post response php

Tags: php, post, curl, laravel-5

I have a code like this

```
    $payUrl = (some url);
    $postCheckData = 'CompanyCode=' . urlencode($companyCode) . '&ServiceCode=' . urlencode($serviceCode) and so on

    $chOne = curl_init( $payUrl );
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postCheckData);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $payResp = curl_exec( $chOne );
    curl_close ($chOne);
    print_r($payResp);
```

When I try to run this code, I get `curl_setopt(): 248 is not a valid cURL handle resource`
What is this error? None of the solutions that I have searched worked for me.. What can be the possible problem? Please help

Comment: Use $chOne instead of $ch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you initialise the curl request using  $chOne = curl_init( $payUrl ); but then refer to $ch for all the other  curl_setopt calls. I think it should look like this:

```
$payUrl = (some url);
$postCheckData = 'CompanyCode=' . urlencode($companyCode) . '&ServiceCode=' . urlencode($serviceCode) and so on

$chOne = curl_init( $payUrl );
curl_setopt( $chOne, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt( $chOne, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt( $chOne, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $chOne, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postCheckData);
curl_setopt( $chOne, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $chOne, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $chOne, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$payResp = curl_exec( $chOne );
curl_close( $chOne );

print_r( $payResp );
```